# Nokogiri::HTML#to_htmlのエンコーディング処理で失敗する

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

こちらのページを解析したく
http://www.monex.co.jp/DealInfo/00000000/sinyo/meig/kiseiichiran/hyji?mop=

```
url = 'http://www.monex.co.jp/DealInfo/00000000/sinyo/meig/kiseiichiran/hyji?mop='
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, 'r:CP932'))
doc.to_html(encoding: 'cp932')
```

とすると以下のエラーになってしまいます。

```
encoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x97 0x70 0xC2 0x83
```

encodingを`shift_jis`にしても結果は同じですし、`to_html`に引数をつけないと`unknown encoding name - x-sjis`のエラーになってしまいました。

どうエンコーディング処理の指定をするのが正しいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nokogiri::HTML`は第一引数が`#encoding`に反応すればそれを利用し、反応しない場合ソースのmetaヘッダ等から類推しようとします。

```
source = open(url).read
source.encoding #=> #<Encoding:Shift_JIS>
Nokogiri::HTML(source).encoding #=> 'Shift_JIS'
# したがって
Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read).encoding #=> 'Shift_JIS'

#一方で
f = open(url)
f.encoding #=> NoMethodError
Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)).encoding #=> 'x-sjis'  (metaヘッダに由来)
```

今回のようにmetaヘッダからの推測では不都合がある場合など、文字エンコーディングを明示的に指定する場合は第三引数で設定します。

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open(url), nil, 'Shift_JIS').encoding # => 'Shift_JIS'
```

問題はパーサに不適切なエンコーディングが指定されてしまっていることです。`#to_html`に渡すエンコーディングは出力時のものなので、ここに何を指定するかは問題とは無関係です。

Answer (score -1):

こちらの環境は以下の通りです。

- Ruby 2.1.2
- Nokogiri 1.6.3

エンコーディングは対象のウェブページから取得してしまえば良いのではないでしょうか。以下のコードではエラーメッセージは表示されずに正常終了します。

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://www.monex.co.jp/DealInfo/00000000/sinyo/meig/kiseiichiran/hyji?mop='

charset = nil
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(
  open(url) do |f|
    charset = f.charset
    f.read
  end
)

puts doc.to_html(encoding: charset).to_s
```

Comment: これで動くのは`Nokogiri.HTML(open(url))`を実質的に`Nokogiri.HTML(open(url).read)`に書き換えたためです。charsetは無関係です。